# What is the ls option to list entries by lines instead of by columns?

Tags: linux

What is the ls option to list entries by lines instead of by columns?

Comment: `man ls | grep -e "list one file per line"`

Answer (score 0):

The

```
ls -1
```

command will list entries one per line. More generally, you can use the

```
--format=<WORD>
```

option. Here *<WORD>* should be one of the words listed on the left column below:

```
across         -x
commas         -m
horizontal     -x
long           -l
single-column  -1
verbose        -l
vertical       -C
```

where the one letter options given on the right colum are just shorthands for the longer version.